# c++ что означают данные строки?

Tags: c#, c++, c++-cli

Имеется фрагмент когда

```
pin_ptr<const wchar_t> wch = PtrToStringChars(source);
auto ptr = reinterpret_cast<void const *>(wch);
const int Length = source->Length;
wchar_t * const data = new wchar_t[Length];
memcpy(data, ptr, Length * sizeof(wchar_t));
```

`source`- поступает в качестве параметра функции.
Объясните пожалуйста,  что делают данные функции, это просто копирование строки с одной переменной в другую? Перевожу данный код на c#

Comment: Копирование из ptr в data

Comment: то есть var data = prt; ?

Comment: похоже, но не совсем. На выходе получается массив wchar_t, а не string, source, наверное, был указателем на массив (какой тип у source ?) и копирование происходило по значению. Это c++ CLI?

Comment: В методе поступает тип string,  да,  это c++cli.  Я не могу данный фрагмент кода перенести на c#

Comment: если data сделать тоже string, то да, по сути эквивалент `var data = ptr;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Данный фрагмент преобразует управляемую строку .NET в массив широких символов С++ и размещает его в динамической памяти. При этом он содержит потенциальную проблему: память под завершающий нуль-символ не выделяется, поэтому такой массив не будет корректно обработан многими функциями стандартной библиотеки для работы со строками (это может и не быть проблемой в конкретном коде, но помнить об этом полезно).

В C# обычно нет необходимости в таком преобразовании в явном виде, так как String имеет метод ToCharArray для преобразования в массив символов, а при вызове нативных функций маршаллер P/Invoke умеет автоматически преобразовывать объекты string (или StringBuilder) в неуправляемые строки. Близким аналогом является метод [Marshal.StringToHGlobalUni](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.stringtohglobaluni?view=netframework-4.7.2), но он выделяет память под нуль-символ. Совсем буквальный перевод будет выглядеть как-то так:

```
IntPtr data = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(source.Length);
Marshal.Copy(source.ToCharArray(), 0, data, source.Length);
```